# flex 4: while in a vgroup, how can i add a moveable element that won't be part of the vgroup?

Tags: apache-flex, layout, flex4

I created several components that are placed inside a VGroup.

in one of the components code, i want to add an image and to move it. i don't want the image to be part of the vgroup and to be bound to the vgroup area, i want it to be like float in css. how can I do that?

## update

I want to be able to move the element in the entire area of the application. not to move it within the vgroup. i don't want this object to be attached to any container besides the main application window in order for me not to have limits how much can i move it and where.

example.

If i created a new mxml component called test that extends a VGroup component.
inside that vgroup i want to be able to do something like

```
Main_Application_Window.addElement(myElement)
```

which will allow me create animate that will move the element through the entire screen.

thanks!

Comment: I think we need more information to be able to answer this.  What do you mean by "move" the image?  Moving it within the context of the component that's in the VGroup, or within the VGroup itself?  What behavior are you looking for specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the VGroup control things outside of its boundaries seems like a violation of OO principles to me.  A more common approach would be to have your custom VGroup dispatch a custom event, which your main application would be listening for, and have the main application handle creating/placing/moving the element around.  Hope that helps.